# Smtp server issue starttls command to sslsocket but when startHandshake() read time out

Tags: java, sslsocketfactory

```
    public static Socket createSsl(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) (factory.createSocket(socket, socket
        .getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), socket.getPort(), true));
    sslsocket.setUseClientMode(false);
    sslsocket.startHandshake();
    return sslsocket;
  }
```

the sslsocket always read time out when sslsocket.startHandshake(), so what should I do to solve the problem?